# Android VideoView fullscreen keep aspect ratio center

Tags: java, android

I am working with a splash screen on my app. I'd like to have a background video in it. My video resolution is 1280x720 and it has to be position in a fullscreen portrait mode.

My code works but then, it stretches the height of the video.

What I want to to get it's center view while the height is 100% fit on the screen.

[image]

```
VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(videoView);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.splash);
videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
videoview.start();

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    tools:context="cn.nekocode.camerafilter.splash">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?